# How can we set \displaystyle for a whole text?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, display-math-mode

Since there is no preamble to set \displaystyle for the whole text, how can we do to avoid writing \displaystyle each time we write a new formula?

(but I still want to write inline)

For example if I want to write this :

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} u_k$ is ... so we have $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} u_k ^2 = ...$, and it implies that $\sum ...$. but I don't want to write \displaystyle each time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ummm, use `$$<content>$$`

Comment: Yes but I want to write inline.

Comment: This seems a bit unusual to me. What are actually the places where you need displaystyle? Do you need it for limits/integrals? Or do you want to have bigger fractions?

Comment: Actually both : mostly when i use sums and integrals

Comment: `$\displaystyle{........................................................}$`

Comment: But please, @math, do *not* use display style in titles!

Comment: yes i know about that, thank you @amWhy, i edited my question to be clearer

Comment: I do not know about a solution to change the whole post to displaystyle. But, for example, one could use $\newcommand\sumi[3]{\sum\limits_{#1=#2}^{#3}}$`$\newcommand\sumi[3]{\sum\limits_{#1=#2}^{#3}}$` in the post (somewhere near to the beginning) to shorten all sums to something like `$\sumi k0n\binom nk$` $\sumi k0n\binom nk$. Your example would look like: 
`$\sumi k1n u_k$ is ... so we have $\sumi k1n u_k ^2 =$` $\sumi k1n u_k$ is ... so we have $\sumi k1n u_k ^2 =$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! it's very useful.

Comment: In my opinion, `\displaystyle` should be very seldomly used. If you want it to be big, make it appear in the center with `$$...$$`. Otherwise, you make paragraphs have too much spacing so they do not flow as easily as they should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is not really a way to force display style math without invoking `\displaystyle` every time you enter "math mode" using a single dollar sign.  There is probably some hackery which could be made to work (as [Martin Sleziak suggests](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32944/how-can-we-set-displaystyle-for-a-whole-text#comment148687_32944)), but this is not really ideal.
2. You shouldn't do this, anyway.  Display style mathematics  really ought to be reserved for displayed equations and expressions.  Putting  display style mathematics inline monkeys with line spacing, and creates a rather inconsistently  typeset document.  $\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_k$ is  correct.   $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} u_k$ really isn't  (note how it stretches the interline-spacing).